# How do I make a HTML form using <label> <input> and <span>?

Tags: forms, input, label, html

I have made a form in HTML using a table and that worked fine, however, my teacher told me that making forms from tables is not the proper way to do it anymore, instead I should use:

```
<form>
 <label></label>
 <input>
</form>
```

but he also mentioned something about using `<span></span>` and I'll guess it is just about this point where I got a bit confused, because where should I use it - ie. should I put the `<label>` and the `<input>` in between `<span></span>` ?

A few of the reason I ask is:

1. I don't consider myself very savvy when it comes to HTML
2. I would just have used a `<div></div>` to wrap around the `<label>` and the `<input>` and then use css to put it where I want it to appear on the webpage.

Regarding the form I want to create then I want it to look like this:

```
[Firstname] [lastname]
[textfield] [textfield]
[Street]    [zip-code]  [city]
[textfield] [textfield] [textfield]
[E-mail]    [Phone]
[textfield] [textfield]
[message]
[textarea]
```

I hope the layout of my form makes sense to the majority of you !

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
<form action="action.php">
  <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="firstName"><br>

  <label for="lastName">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="lname" id="lastName"><br>
  ....
</form>
```

and to line it all up you could use some css like this:

```
label{
      width: 100px;
      text-align:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you could use SPAN technically.. as it's an inline element and so are LABEL and INPUT, it doesn't quite sit well. Inline elements aren't really designed to be containers, so using a block level element such as a DIV would be a better way of structuring it.

Beyond this to make it line up, you're moving into the relms of CSS to float your elements.

So something alone the lines of:

```
<form action="">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="left">
            <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName">
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <label for="LastName">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<style type="text/css">

fieldset {
    width:500px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

fieldset .left {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
fieldset .right {
    float:right;
    width:50%;
}
fieldset label {
    display:block;
}
fieldset block {
    display:block;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Your example is indeed very similar to what I would have done myself, which leads me to conclude that I have misunderstood what my teacher told me.

Answer (score 0):

You teacher probably means that you should wrap each pair of `input` and `label` in a `span`. You are quite right in thinking that you should use `div` instead of `span` there. Just tell your teacher to look at the page when style sheets are disabled. On similar grounds, you should prove her/him that he is all wrong about saying that a `table` should not be used.

To do the exercise of writing a form (that is essentially tabular data) without using `table` markup, just use your `div` approach and use tabular layout features of CSS: set `display: table` on the `form`, `display: table-row` on the `div` elements, and `display: table-cell` on the `input` and `label` elements. Add padding and horizontal alignment as needed. Do not forget to inform your teacher that this will only work on sufficiently modern browsers, whereas the logical approach of using an HTML `table` works on all browsers.

Comment: [quote]You teacher probably means that you should wrap each pair of input and label in a span[/quote]  Yes, as I recall, that was exactly what he told me ! however, as I wrote in my comment @Ricky S (the post above your) this leads me to a similar conclusion, so I think I'll need to have my teacher explain it to me once more, so I don't waste yours and other user's time. My teacher also mentioned something about the ability to show a user if a form field were filled out correctly by showing for example a green "ok" text after the input field - maybe it is here the `span` comes into play ?

Comment: @NeoFox1972, your teacher is simply wrong. You can learn from his mistakes, but that’s the only reason for asking for explanations. Use of `span` (vs. `div`, or `table` markup) has nothing to do with showing whether fields have been filled correctly – such things depend on client-side JavaScript, or (if the form is submitted and then errors are reported) on server-side form handler. The way to add error/correctness signals depends on the markup used, but only in a trivial way.

Comment: `@Jukka`I must admit that while he was explaining the usefulness of making forms using `label`,`input` and `span` it made good sense to me, this lead me to conclude that I'm simply not telling you everything he said exactly as he said it to me (my apology for that). I'll talk to him as soon as I get back to school again and have him explain it again (and take notes if I have to) then I'll post what he said. In addition to teaching my teacher also have a small company which develop mobile apps and I know he has a bachelors degree in web development, so he must know what he is talking about

Comment: "@Jukka", I have talking to my teacher and have him explain why we use <label> instead of <div>. the reason is that is semantic more correct to do it this way - using <label>, <span> and <input> will produce a more clean form semantically. The advantage is also that using <label> instead of <div> will make the whole form area interactive instead of just the input field, this is usefull in mobile apps where there isn't a lot of space. I hope this explanation was helpful for you - sorry for not getting back earlier.

Comment: The explanation makes no sense. The use of `div` and the use of `label` are independent choices; `div` relates to grouping, `label` *functionally* connects a label with a control. The rest is even more obscure and just tries to convince you with buzzwords like “mobile apps”.